# Addressing ISA card with pascal

Tags: pascal

I have an old pascal program (code on request) which should address a custom fabricated isa card. I already know which ports are responsible for which function on the isa card, but now I need to connect this to the pascal program. I also know how to address ports in pascal (like this: `port[addr]:=nnn;` or `mmm:=port[addr];`), but I do not know what the hexadecimal numbers mean (e.g. `$03A2`). So, which number should I use if I want to address for example Pin A2 at the ISA card? Or did I forget something (like selecting the right isa connector)?
For clarification: With `Pin A2` I am referring to the following scheme: http://www.nullmodem.com/images/conn_busisa16ma.gif
I don't care if the card is reacting to my signals, I simply want to send a bit to `Pin A2` of the ISA port...

Comment: have you read the card's datasheet?

Comment: As I have written, the card is custom fabricated and therefore has no datasheet (and it is ~24-25 years old, as I assume)...

Comment: well...that's hard, datasheet is what's supposed to be available, since I believe there won't be hard marks in the card to show which port does what. there's no standard for that AFAIK.

Comment: Well, I already know which port does what, I just need the command in pascal for each port (e.g. set ISA Port A1 to high), nothing more...

Comment: You've already indicated you know how to read and write ports if you know the port address in hex. So it's unclear what your question is about. Did you already try something and it didn't work? What does "port A1" mean? Is it a bit in a port with a given hex address? Any bit should be associated with a port address (in hex) and a bit number (bit position).

Comment: @lurker: Clarification added

Comment: @arc_lupus `A2` is data `D7` which is a much more logical way to describe it. Now that we're saying you want to write a bit to data bit 7, the question is: with what port address? Logically, you would select a port *and* a data value to read or write, because any given ISA card only listens to specific ports (if normally designed). If it really doesn't matter what the port address is, then you can pick any port that is mapped to your ISA card, which gets back to needing to know something about the design of the card (what ports does it listen to?).

Comment: @lurker: The card has its address lines on A30 and A31, and the data lines are on A2-A9. How did you translate A2 to D7?

Comment: I was looking at a diagram of the [ISA 16 connector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Industry_Standard_Architecture#mediaviewer/File:ISA_Bus_pins.png) and comparing with your diagram and came up with data bit 7. As you noted, data lines are on A2-A9. A2 is bit 7, A3 is bit 6, and so on. I just used "D7" as short for "data bit 7". I apologize, as it's a poor choice of symbolism on my part given that there's something labeled D7 already.

Comment: @lurker: And how do I access this bit with pascal?

Comment: You would write a data value that has the 7th bit set to a port that the card is listening to (if you just want to write the bit without regard at all to what port address you want, per my other comment). More specifically, suppose the card listens on port `$0300`, then you would do something like, `port[$0300] := port[$0300] or $80;` if what you said is true about how to read/write ports with the `port` array. But you must choose a port that only this card listens to. Otherwise, you might be setting that bit for a different card in the system.

Comment: @lurker: And how can I find that specific port out?

Comment: As has been stated: either a data sheet for the card, or reverse engineer design of the card.

Comment: Well, I know how the card works (which pins are used), but I have no data sheets. Can I derive the port number from this?

Comment: Knowing which pins are used isn't exactly "how the cards works". :) What does the card do? What's the purpose of writing to pin A2? Will the card listen to A2 regardless of what port you write to (I think this is unlikely if it's properly designed)? There's really know way to specifically infer the ports from knowing what the card does, unless, for example it's a parallel port card, in which case it might use one of the standard LPT I/O base port numbers. In other words, if there is some standard port normally associated with whatever its function is.

Comment: It is a GPIO-Card which reads data from two different devices, data will be transferred via A2-A9, and the signals for switching the device and for read/write-operations are @A17-A19, A30, A31 and B13/B14. That is all information I could get from the card.

Comment: As others already said, what you need is the address of the port. You only know the port "name" (A1, A2, whatsoever). How it's mapped to memory is something a datasheet should provide. What diagram above provides is nothing but the meaning of the bit values of each port, again, not address. Reverse engineer if you can, otherwise choose a more sane card (those having a datasheet).

Answer (score 0):

As Lelelumbo says, the ISA card just reacts on port I/O addresses on the ISA bus. The meaning is only known to the ISA card. Afaik it is not even possible to detect if a card reacted.

See e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_I/O  (and then specially the port I/O aka Isolated I/O references)

If you can't get a datasheet, reverse engineering the card or (if you are lucky, but that luck is relative) a known driver are your only options. Even if the driver is for a different OS.

Comment: I know how the card works, I just need to know how to get the adress of the different pins of the ISA port...

Comment: The ISA port is an address bus, and its pins can't be individually controlled.